# Note field required even though it has no required attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have the following class:

```
public class UpdateActionRequest
{
    [Required]
    public int ActionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int LeadId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AssignedToUserId { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PlannedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Which I use in an api call:

```
[HttpPatch("update", Name = nameof(UpdateAction))]
public async Task<LeadAction> UpdateAction(UpdateActionRequest request)
{
    return await _actionsHandler.Value.UpdateAction(request);
}
```

But when I send the following JSON:

```
{
  "ActionId":7,
  "LeadId":40,
  "AssignedToUserId": 8306,
  "PlannedDate":"2022-11-14T11:23:45.343Z"
}
```

I'm getting a bad request saying the note field is required - how do I make it so that I don't need to send the note property?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
 public string? Note { get; set; };
```

or

```
 public string Note { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Comment: Hmmm so I went with the second one as the first one seemed to cause other issues.  I thought strings were nullable anyway so why do you need to specify it?

Comment: Note that a property being nullable does not neccesarily mean it is optional vice versa. Actually those are often mixed, although those are completely independant things. That's why we have the `Required`- and `Optional`-attributes. In C#11 we even have an access-modifier `required` for that.

Comment: Probably the default behavior for webAPI is actually to convert an empty string to a
null. and you field is not null and gave Error;

Comment: you can follow this thread https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1830